# Does the Americans With Disabilities Act require accommodations for students whose disability prevents them from behaving ethically?

Tags: united-states, health

Does the Americans With Disabilities Act require accommodations for university students whose disability prevents them from behaving ethically?

Does it forbid punishment of unethical behavior which is caused by a disability?

Comment: This question was indirectly inspired by some less-than-plausible comments on this site.

Comment: Is this a question or a troll?

Comment: @Buffy Well, the person who inspired it might have been trolling me.  Or maybe they actually think the answer is yes?  I'm not sure.  Also, I'm not really an ADA expert.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think it is serious, but rather bait for controversy.

Comment: @Buffy I thought the answer would be "No" and that nobody would debate that.  Am I wrong?  Excepting maybe one person.

Comment: Probably getting information about ADA would better fit at https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GEdgar I don't use that site, so I'm unsure.

Comment: I'm voting to close as well because I can't come up with an example where that would be relevant. If a student actually *harmed* other people habitually, they need to be in a closed mental institution, not a university.

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, if the unethical behaviour is something along the lines of compulsively looking at the answers from the student(s) sitting nearby while taking a test, one *might* consider that if the student let this be known to the professor, the professor might be required to provide an alternate test-taking environment (as is also done for students who require an isolated environment for other reasons).
Behaving dangerously and behaving unethically would likely require a different response, and if dangerous behaviour has occurred, I would doubt the ADA is the applicable statue.

Comment: @Buffy the OP’s motivation for asking the question is irrelevant. It’s a valid, well-posed question (and one that I suspect has a clear and unambiguous answer) that’s clearly in the scope of this site (I personally would be very interested to see an answer from a knowledgeable source). Your close vote is unwarranted IMO.

Comment: Unless there is appropriate case law to the contrary, I don’t think that unethical behavior necessarily is an impairment that substantially limits a major life activity, the basis of the ADA.

Comment: [Ticking, ticking...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kerwt0HQ6I)

Comment: Too abstract. If somebody is a compulsory liar and invents facts and experimental results in their thesis? Somebody who cannot stop hitting fellow students? Somebody who is manipulating students and gaslighting them in group work to squeeze out the best mark without actually being that good in the topic? Somebody who cannot stop throwing out insults (yes, *that* disability)? You need to be more concrete, as it is now, the spectrum of responses is too wide.

Answer (score 6):

Behaving unethically, at least as far as it requires or deserves sanctions, requires an element of choice. If the person had no choice, e.g. because of a disability, then sanctions are not called for.

It is probably my lack of imagination, but I cannot think of an disability that requires students to act unethically.

As to how the law views this: talk to a lawyer or the legal department, or equal opportunities department of your university.

Comment: Interesting, but I don't agree.  Your reasoning would suggest that if a student compulsively harmed other people, I would be obligated to keep teaching them.  I would say that since I teaching things that can be used to harm people, I would be obligated to not teach such a student, even if their actions were involuntary.  Not teaching them is essentially a sanction.

Comment: Hm. "I cannot think of an disability that requires students to act unethically" - it's not a *requirement*, but ["Kleptomania is the inability to resist the urge to steal items"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleptomania). "Inability to resist the urge" does sound very much like "no choice" to me.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Perhaps someone trained in dealing with the disability could teach them instead. That's neither a sanction on the student nor an obligation on you.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I would venture to guess exactly no university professors are trained in instructing people with mental conditions such as these.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist since this is a site on academia and you mentioned university students, I interpreted unethical behavior as plagiarism or cheating. So that reinforces the comments of others, that you need to narrow down your question by specifying what kind of unethical behavior you want to talk about.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Harming others only slightly more complex: you now have two incompatible interests: the disabled students wants to get an education and the other students and faculty don't want to be hurt. If the university decides that it cannot teach that student without endangering others, then that decision is not a sanction. Not every decision that hurts someone is a sanction.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Do you have a reason to think that the law (ADA) cares what the behavior is?

Comment: @MaartenBuis "Not every decision that hurts someone is a sanction."  But decisions that hurt someone in reaction to their behavior are sanctions.  So I disagree.

Comment: Of course what the law should be and what it actually is are two completely different things. Of you want to discuss the law, you need to talk to a lawyer. As to your second comment: It is not enough for a decision to be a reaction, the purpose of an decision must be to punish. Think of being committed to a mental health facility against your will. That is a decision that is a reaction to actions and the person being committed perceives this as hurtful. Still, it is not a sanction.

Comment: Yes, thew law definitely cares what the behavior is. The uni is required to make the schooling accessible. It is not required to fundamentally change the nature of the education.  What accommodations are needed are based on what the disability is.  Bad behavior is not a disability. Mental illness is.